# 404 error with existing file using mod rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like rewrite requests like **mysite.com/order/business** to **mysite.com/order/index.php?tariff=business**

I have this .htaccess located in site root:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule order/(business|personal) order/index.php?tariff=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Index.php exists and is working. But I get a 404 Error.

[image: Google Chrome Network Output]

Where I'm wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

what if you insert delimitars like the line below?

```
RewriteRule ^order/(business|personal)$ order/index.php?tariff=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: forzajuve:) But my regexp is working, I have trouble with redirect, I guess

Comment: finoallafine:) can you provide a log from your server?

Comment: I truncated log file and try again. Now I see only one `File does not exist: /home/***/***/***/public_html/home`. Hm.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Change to `/order/index.php?tariff=$1`. Now rewrite works on my localhost, but on shared hosting redirect happens (url is changing). do you know why?

Comment: Why wouldn't a redirect happen if your rule says R=301 explicitly?